# Spyder 4.1.5 disable selected pycodestyle warnings

Tags: python, spyder, pycodestyle

After updating Spyder to 4.1.5 my script is covered with a whole bunch of taste-specific alerts like:

> Code analysis: 
> E261 at least two spaces before inline comment (pycodestyle E261)

or

> Code analysis: 
> E266 too many leading '#' for block comment (pycodestyle E266)

While many of the warnings improve my code, I would like to disable the ones that I disagree with (like for example the two listed above).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I have found it
`Tools -> Preferences -> Completion and linting -> Code Style` then mark the checkbox `Enable code style linting` and then list all the unwanted warnings, separate them with commas.